# How to fetch value from url in silverstripe

Tags: silverstripe

I want to print value 5 on the ss page.

> www.xyz.com?a=5.

How to fetch url data in silverstripe? Any help is accepeted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your controller that your Silverstripe template is for, you can retrieve "GET" (aka. query string) by returning the result of [`$this->getRequest()->getVar('a')`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-SS_HTTPRequest.html#_getVar) in a function on your controller.

It is good practice to use `$this->getRequest()->getVar('a')` over `$_GET['a']` as SilverStripe will automatically sanitise the string.

When your code is not in the controller (so you can't make use of `$this->getRequest()`), you can [request the current controller by using `Controller::curr()`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Controller.html#_curr) which will make the complete call for getting a single var:

```
Controller::curr()->getRequest()->getVar('a')
```

If you want to get all "GET" variables, [just call `getVars()` instead.](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-SS_HTTPRequest.html#_getVars).

Also, you can access "POST" variables in a similar calling [`postVar('a')`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-SS_HTTPRequest.html#_postVar) or [`postVars()`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-SS_HTTPRequest.html#_postVars) instead. If you want to get the value from both "POST" or "GET", you can call [`requestVar('a')`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-SS_HTTPRequest.html#_requestVar) or [`requestVars()`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-SS_HTTPRequest.html#_requestVars).

Anyway, here is a basic mock-up of a controller using a function on the controller that is accessible in the template.

**Controller**

```php
class TestPage_Controller extends Page_Controller
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
    }

    public function MySpecialProperty()
    {
        return $this->getRequest()->getVar('a');
    }
}
```

**Template**

```
<p> $MySpecialProperty </p>
```