# Keeping special characters for parameters (php)

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am grabbing the parameter from the URL with SilverStripe ([How to fetch value from url in silverstripe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28560679/how-to-fetch-value-from-url-in-silverstripe)), which looks like this if I were to look at the url itself:

```
dg%0D%0Acer
```

Yet when I save it as a variable and return it, it is converted to this:

```
dgcer

$terms = (empty($this->getRequest()->postVar('terms'))) ? ((empty($this->getRequest()->getVar('terms'))) ? '' : $this->getRequest()->getVar('terms')) : $this->getRequest()->postVar('terms');
```

I need to keep that space between the two items.  How do I do this?  It keeps getting stripped.

Comment: No need to check both, GET and POST manually, you can simply use `$this->requestVar('terms')` which will check GET and POST (POST is used if both have this var set). And `%0D%0A` is a line break, no simple space.

Comment: So then how can I keep the line break?